# Initialize new arraylist with (custom) items in one line in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

In Kotlin I created an extension function to initialise a new ArrayList with custom items, like this:

```
fun <T> arrayListFrom(vararg item: T): ArrayList<T> {
    return item.toMutableList() as ArrayList<T>
}
```

In this way I can easily create an arraylist like this

```
arrayListFrom(MyCustomItem(1), MyCustomItem(2))
```

... without creating a new-empty one, and adding all elements to it one by one

Kotlin has so many useful functions for collections, I cannot imagine I need this extension for easy arrayList initialisation, but couldn't find another simple way. Am I missing out on some useful Kotlin function here?

Comment: arrayListOf() https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html ?

Comment: BTW, that's not an extension function. It's just a function.

Comment: How do you know that `.toMutableList()` returns an `ArrayList`?  It's not specified in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html), so there's no guarantee.  Even if the cast works for you today, it could well fail in a future version of Kotlin (e.g. if they find/write a different `MutableList` implementation to return).

Comment: Yup, not an extension function, my wrong!

And good point gidds, it's not a great solution, but worked for me for now. I was looking for a better implementation anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arrayListOf(items)`, documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html).

So you can just do

`arrayListOf(MyCustomItem(1), MyCustomItem(2))`

Answer (score 0):

One more easy way to initialize ArrayList not exactly one line.

```
object: ArrayList<instanceType>() {
        init{
            add(instance1)
            add(instance2)
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another nifty trick is to leverage Kotlin's basic Array type. Its constructor has an optional init function which allows for cool and simple inits like so `val newArray = Array(2) { MyCustomItem(i+1) }` which would make `[ MyCustomItem(1), MyCustomItem(2) ]`.

To get an arrayList out of it, just add `toCollection(ArrayList())` to the end like so

`val newArrayList = Array(2) { MyCustomItem(i+1) }.toCollection(ArrayList())`

and presto! The array gets created, and the items get sent to a destination arrayList. You can use the arrayList as needed, and it was done in only one line!

Disclaimer: It's probably slower given the transfer involved under the hood, so use with care of course!

Answer (score 0):

```
    object Utils {
        fun stringArray(size: Int): ArrayList<String> {
            val strings = ArrayList<String>()
            for (i in 0 until size) strings.add("")
            return strings
        }
        
        fun booleanArray(size: Int): BooleanArray {
            val booleans = BooleanArray(size)
            Arrays.fill(booleans, false)
            return booleans
        }
    }
    
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val strings = Utils.stringArray(5)
    val booleans = Utils.booleanArray(8)
    
    strings[0] = "test"
    booleans[2] = true
    }
```